# how may I get a p.value from chisq.test() function?

Tags: r, chi-squared

```
m1 <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, d=0)
chisq.test(m)$p.value
# 0.3678794

m2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,0), b=c(2,12,0), d=c(0,0,0))
chisq.test(m2)$p.value
# NaN
```

I cannot understand why the `chisq.test()` function cannot test the difference of a table like m2. Is there any method to get a p value for data frame like m1 with the third column of zeros?

Comment: _"I cannot understand why..."_ - it's because `chisq.test(m1)$expected` has `0`s (division by zero => `NaN`), and the expected freqs in `chisq.test(m1)$expected` are `c(1,1,1)/3  * sum(c(1,2,0))` = `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marco demonstrated, [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) will give you a p-value, but even if the χ<sup>2</sup>-test did give you a value you still should have used Fisher's. The χ<sup>2</sup>-test gives an approximate and is only suited for large datasets.
As to why you get a `NaN`, lukeA is correct, although you could state the same by saying that the test won't work if any row or column sums to zero, or has zero marginals.

```
m2 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 0), b=c(2, 12, 0), d=c(0, 0, 0))
chisq.test(m2, simulate.p.value=TRUE)$p.value

# Warning messages:
# 1: In chisq.test(m2, simulate.p.value = TRUE) :
# cannot compute simulated p-value with zero marginals
```

To demonstrate the difference between approximate and exact p-value

```
m3 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 0), b=c(2, 12, 0), d=c(0, 0, 1))

chisq.test(m3, simulate.p.value=TRUE)$p.value
# 0.05147

fisher.test(m3)$p.value
# 0.06324
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fisher's exact test:

```
 fisher.test(m1)$p.value
```

[1] 0.4647059